# my WSL ubuntu vi editor screen is broken when I scroll down

Tags: ubuntu, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vimrc, vi

When I scroll down at my vim editor, all of my codes is wrapped with strange boxes. Can I fix it?

My .vimrc file:
[image: Problem Image]

Problem Image:
[image: My .vimrc file]

Comment: Is this at the end of the lines? Perhaps it is the end-of-line character.

Comment: @harrymc yeap, It always happened end of the lines. It there any good soulutions not to be appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be a problem.

Your text seem to be a mixture of lines handled by Windows and Linux text-editors.

However, while Linux uses only one character : Linefeed (LF), Windows uses
two: Carriage-return+Linefeed.

You could either use always the same editor, or just accept this display.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Then can I set only linefeed via vimrc?

Comment: You will still have a mix of inconsistent line-endings, which probably can still work without any real problem. Read this article from the Vim Tips Wiki for fuller understanding of the subject: [File format](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_format). However, you should avoid using text-editors from Windows and Linux on the same files, use Linux for Linux and Windows for Windows.

Comment: I fixed it!! https://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html